# Angular easiest way to bind an array to one value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the easiest way in angular to bind **one** value to an array of values so that all array items get the **same value** e.g. of an input when it changes.

```
<script>
     var myArray= [1,1,1];  
</script>

<input ng-model="myArray" type="text" />
```

Comment: Do you have a particular use-case for this? It seems very inefficient to be storing the same data multiple times - maybe there is a better way to solve your problem?

Comment: Is this Array a fixed length one or dynamic?

Comment: it is dynamic. Leon answered already. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use the ngChange directive to call a function binding the new value to all the elements:

```js
 angular.module('changeExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
     function($scope) {
       $scope.valueToCopy = '';
       $scope.values = values = [1, 1, 1, 3, 6];
       $scope.change = function() {
         for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           values[i] = $scope.valueToCopy;
         }
         console.log(values);
       };
     }
   ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="changeExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Copy this:
  <input ng-model="valueToCopy" ng-change="change()" />

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">Element at {{$index}} = {{value}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `$watch` the value of the input variable, and then update the array, something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myArray = [];

  $scope.$watch('arrayValue', function(val){
    $scope.myArray = [val,val,val];
  })
});
------------------------------------------
<input type="text" ng-model="arrayValue">
{{ myArray }}
```